# Visualforce Input Fields Not Binding in Nested Iteration Components

Tags: visualforce

I have created a copy/paste code sample that replicates the issue:

### Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="test" action="{!init}">
    <apex:form id="renderTarget">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="rerender" reRender="renderTarget" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:repeat value="{!parents}" var="int">
                <apex:variable var="children" value="{!parents[int].children}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!children}" var="child">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!child.selected}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### Apex

```
public class test {
    public Map<Integer, Parent> parents {get; set;}

    public void init() {
       parents = new Map<Integer, Parent>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            parents.put(i, new Parent());

            for (Integer x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                parents.get(i).children.add(new Child());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Parent {
        public List<Child> children {get; set;}

        public Parent() {
            children = new List<Child>();
        }
    }

    public class Child {
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public Child() {
            selected=false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Steps to reproduce

If you select any of the checkboxes from the first 2 tables and click the rerender button, you will see the values removed from the checkboxes.

If you select any boxes in the final table and click the rerender button, the values will remain.

Selecting any combination of checkboxes from any table will result in the first two tables being deselected while the third keeps it's selections.

### More info

I had thought I saw an answer for a similar issue here but can't seem to find it.

I've tried with repeats and datatables and the behavior is the same, I used pageblock tables as they provide a cleaner visual.

I thought that it might be related to the `name` property of the checkbox in the generated html. In a more realistic example, the tables do not have exactly 3 items. I tested samples to verify that the name attribute is not necessarily the issue. Even still, this name is pulled from the Id of the checkbox and SFDC does not allow dynamically identified components.

I feel like this is pretty basic stuff and I'm embarrassed to even ask but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`apex:variable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm) is **not** supported in iterators. The documentation states this explicitly:

> Note: `<apex:variable>` does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as `<apex:dataTable>` or `<apex:repeat>`. The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the `<apex:variable>` as a counter, is unsupported and undefined.

Sometimes it works, but in this case, it's probably unsupported behavior. Convert the Map to a List, and iterate over that, instead:

```
public Parent[] getParentList() {
    return parents.values();
}
```

---

```
<apex:repeat value="{!parentList}" var="parent">
```

---

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!parent.children}" var="child">
```

---

The thing about the way apex:variable works is that all of the checkboxes will actually be bound to whatever the last element in the iteration is. It's kind of difficult to demonstrate, but I can try to craft an example later. Just know that because of the variable assignment, the checkboxes are all getting mapped to the same instance of children, and if they were different lengths, this could even cause more undesirable behavior. Like the documentation says, the behavior is undefined, and you shouldn't try to use apex:variable in a loop.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on this a few years ago: https://laceysnr.com/checking-boxes-geting-input/

It uses a list and a map together, allowing you to loop over the list of records but uses a map of Id -> Boolean to capture checkbox input.

Comment: @MattLacey Yeah, I've used that design as well. This was just the first thing that came to my head to minimize disruption to the current code.